# What is the difference between andoid:xxx and xxx?

Tags: android, android-styles

I want to change the color of Dialog's NegativeButton;

Here's a natural way to do it through styles:

> values-21/styles.xml

```
<style name="BaseDialogStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="NegativeButtonBarButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ffff</item>
</style>
```

but ,if i change the name to `android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle`, it not work.Why is that?

Many thanks~

Answer (score 0):

"android" is the package prefix for the attribute ressource. The prefix depends on the resource you are using.

```
<item name="[package:]style_property_name">style_value</item>
```

( From : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html )

Generally "android" is used for elements and widgets already defined by android. There is generally no prefix when the attribute is for the customization of the application itself